# ¿Cómo hago en Android Studio para que el código se coloque correctamente?

Tags: android-studio

He copiado un código de una página, pero no se ha colocado correctamente las llaves en su sitio y me gustaría saber como hacerlo. Pongo un pequeño ejemplo:

```
//boton resta
        Button btnresta=(Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnResta);
        btnresta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        EditText txtentreda = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TxtEntrada);
        String numero = txtentreda.getText().toString();
        numero1=Double.parseDouble(numero);
        operacion=2;
        numero=" ";
        txtentreda.setText(numero);
        }
        });
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Pulsando `Control + Alt + L` [ver aquí lista completa de atajos del teclado](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts). Hay muchas otras formas [ver esta pregunta y sus respuestas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22411280/5587982).

Comment: Haciendo eso me bloquea el teclado. Tengo instalado el Ubuntu

Comment: @gulez es diferente en cada plataforma, en Ubuntu  sería : Ctrl + Shift + Alt + L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo desde el menú superior del mismo IDE

- `Code / Reformat Code`

A la derecha tendrás la combinación de teclas correspondiente a tu sistema para poder invocar el reformateo de código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ver una referencia completa de los atajos de teclado en Android Studio puedes consultar: [Combinaciones de teclas](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts) en Android Developers

Answer (score 1):

Sin el atajo de teclado tienes que pulsar en Code, que es el quinto elemento del menú superior de Android Studio, y ahí pulsas en Reformat Code, y ahí también te pondrá que atajo de teclado te sirve, en Windows como te dijo Cedano es Ctrl + Alt+ L, mira cual te funciona a ti.

Answer (score 1):

Esto es algo simple y muy importante para poder indentar tu código. 
Puedes utilizar los siguientes atajos según el sistema operativo que utilices:

Windows

> Ctrl + Alt + L

Linux

> Ctrl + Shirft + Alt + L

Mac

> Option + Command + L

Answer (score -1):

Para dar formato a tu código en `Android Studio`:

En Windows:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

En Mac:

> <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

En Linux:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

---

Revisa también :

[**Estilo y Formato en Android Studio.**](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/#estilo_y_formato)

> Mientras editas, Android Studio aplica automáticamente formatos y
>   estilos según lo especificado en tu configuración de estilo de código.
>   Puedes personalizar la configuración de estilo de código programando
>   el idioma, que incluye la especificación de convenciones para pestañas
>   y sangrías, espacios, ajuste y llaves, y líneas en blanco. Para
>   personalizar la configuración de estilo de tu código, haz clic en

Windows:

`File  >  Settings > Editor > Code Style`.

Mac:

`Preferences > Editor > Code Style`.

Comment: **CP 301 Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.